# xamarin camera - No overload for method 'Exists' takes '1' arguments

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to use the camera in Xamarin and have a method that gets a unique path as follows

```
    private string GetUniquePath(string path, string name)
    {
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(name);
        if (ext == string.Empty)
            ext = ".jpg";

        name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name);

        string newName = name + ext;
        int i=1;

        while (File.Exists(Path.Combine(path,newName)))
            newName = name + "_" + (i++) + ext;

        return Path.Combine(path, newName);
    }
```

I get an error with -- while (File.Exists(Path.Combine(path,newName)))

The error is no overload for method 'Exists' takes 1 argument.

Yet thats the same format I see everywhere. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error CS1501: No overload for method `Exists' takes`1' arguments

I would assume that it is picking up `Java.IO.File.Exists` which does not take any arguments.

Try fully qualifying the namespaces:

```
while (System.IO.File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(path,newName)))
            newName = name + "_" + (i++) + ext;
```